# Insertion into custom Map function

Tags: java, dictionary, bufferedreader

Ok so I am trying to create a new Map for my assignment. I am unsure how to insert it into this type. The main goal is to read a file, use the first line of the file as the name/key for the map and then add the second line into the second part of the map. I am just having trouble with the actual insertion. There is allot of code not in there for the main function back I just want help with the actual insertion:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TimetableReader {

    private static Map<Route, List<Service>> timeTable;


    public static Map<Route, List<Service>> read(String fileName)
            throws IOException, FormatException {
        timeTable.put(key, value)
        /* Reads in the file */
        try
          {
          FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(fileName); // Creates a new input stream
          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in)); // Creates a new Buffer Reader
          String strLine; // Creates Variable that will represent each line
          /* Processes the lines in the file */
          boolean newRoute = true;  
          int routeNumber = 0;

          while((strLine = br.readLine())!= null)
          {

            if  (newRoute == true) {
                newRoute = false;
                timeTable[routeNumber] = strLine;
            }



          }/* END - Process file */

          }catch(Exception e){
           System.out.println(e);
          }
        /* END - Read file */


        return  timeTable;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert into `Map` use `put(K,V)` method, `K` is key and `V` is value.

```
//timeTable[routeNumber] = strLine;
timeTable.put(K, V);
```

Your map key should be type of `Route` and value type should be `List<String>`

See java api [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems with your code but let's start with what you are asking:
the object timeTable is a [map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) and you are using it as an (associative) array, don't think of the keys as numbers but instead think of them as objects, any type of object could be a key; you will have to change the code and do something like the following:

```
if  (newRoute == true) {
    newRoute = false;
    timeTable.put(routeNumber, strLine);
}
```

The problems I see with your code are these:

- As per timeTable declaration the map is using a Route object as key and a List of Service as value; you are trying to put an Integer (using [autoboxing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)) as key and a String as the value.
- You should close your input stream in a finally block; is always good practice to close any open resources after you are done using them.

Hope it helps.